# How to use ALTER TABLE to add a new column and make it unique?

Tags: sql, unique, alter-table

How do I use `ALTER TABLE` to add a new column and make it unique?

Comment: What database server? More information please.

Answer (score 29):

Depends on the DBMS, but I think the following is quite portable:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name datatype
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD UNIQUE (column_name)
```

If you want to give a name to the `UNIQUE` constraint, you could replace the last command with this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (column_name)
```

Comment: For example: `ALTER TABLE payments ADD unit NVARCHAR2(128);`

Answer (score 5):

if table is empty

```
  ALTER TABLE ADD (FieldName Type)
  ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE(FieldName)
```

If you have data in table you need to this in three steps:

1. Add column
2. Fill values
3. Add unique constraint

Comment: As @APC noted, `UNIQUE` allows multiple `NULL` values, so there is no need to do it in three steps if there is data in the table.

Comment: @Daniel, oracle is allow do this, sql server no allow (until you change settings)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a single SQL statement (at least with MySQL):

```
ALTER TABLE `people` ADD COLUMN `personal_code` VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE AFTER `surname`;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a two step process: add the new coloumn, then add the constraint.  Because UNIQUE constraints permit nulls it doesn't matter whether the table is populated:

```
SQL> select count(*) from t23
  2  /

  COUNT(*)
----------
         2


SQL> alter table t23
  2      add new_col number
  3  /

Table altered.

SQL> alter table t23
  2      add constraint t23_uk unique (new_col)
  3  /

Table altered.

SQL>
```