# Oracle 11g - add new column and set as unique

Tags: sql, oracle11g, unique, alter

I am facing a problem on how to set a new column to unique using Oracle 11g.

I try to use this code but it getting error:

```
ALTER TABLE QAS_ASSIGNED_STATE ADD UNIQUE (cuid);
```

Comment: You are trying to add a new column (cuid) to the table. That column should have a unique constraint?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ALTER TABLE to add a new column and make it unique?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734891/how-to-use-alter-table-to-add-a-new-column-and-make-it-unique)

Comment: @jarlh I am not very sure. But what I know is the table already have unique id (ID)

Comment: @Chrisrs2292 I have followed one of the solution but it does not work,

Comment: A table can have one primary key, but several unique constraints/keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define column's type. Like this:

```
alter table
    QAS_ASSIGNED_STATE 
 add
    cuid number NULL;
```

and then add constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE QAS_ASSIGNED_STATE ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_cuid  UNIQUE (cuid );
```

Comment: Can you add a NOT NULL column without a default value?

Comment: Only If your table is empty. You are right, I will fix it. Thank you

Comment: @S.Nadezhnyy how can I add a new column and assign it as a unique which the table already have a data? can we do that? I mean the table does not empty

Comment: You shoud add column as nullable (like in my example). Then fill column with values and then create constraint.