# oracle 11g - add new column and set as unique where the table not empty

Tags: sql, oracle11g, unique, alter-table

Before this I already asked about on how to add a new column and set it as a unique. 
[oracle 11g - add new column and set as unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030261/oracle-11g-add-new-column-and-set-as-unique)

It does not have any problem to set a unique to the new column if the table is EMPTY.  But I am facing a problem to set a unique to the new column if the table have a data [NOT EMPTY]

Can I set a unique to the new column that I added if the table is NOT EMPTY?

Comment: What is your error? Unique accepts mulitple NULLs - so it supposed to work fine

Comment: @dcieslak Actually it did not return any error. It successfully adding new column but not set the new column to unique.

Comment: Add your statement that you use to question.

Comment: Add your *statements*, plural; as the question you linked to said, you need separate `alter table` commands. Show both statements, the result you got from them, and if you ran both show why you think it didn't work - how are you checking for uniqueness?